# How do I recruit a graphic designer to help on a project with no funding involved?

Tags: project-management, community

Recognized graphic designers usually charge a fee for their work, but what if this project isn't expecting any funds and is expected to run purely off the community?

How would I attract a graphic designer (or designers) to create logos, web site graphics and other artistic/graphical works?

Comment: How do you attach programmers to a project?

Comment: @Tichodroma, It's usually their interest, but if the project is something that's primarily programming-based (e.g. a open source library / framework) then it would seem there would be different measures to attract a graphic designer.

Comment: Interesting question. Somehow, programmers involved in an open source project seem to be fine (or expected to be fine) with having the code out there under an open source license and do not necessarily expect compensation, while graphics designers almost naturally are expected to never do that. Some people I've talked to claim that this is because Free coding culture is older than Free design culture.

Comment: First, [familiarize yourself with some of the counter-arguments](http://www.nospec.com/) within the design community.

Comment: I've always assumed the majority of developers contribute code because they experience a direct benefit from using the product. For a graphic designer, the benefit may be less direct: by improving the presentation of the product, they can help attract more and better developers who can improve functionality. So, better to look for someone with the necessary skills within or via the community itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visibly crediting their work on the site/product could be seen by some as "payments through advertising".

Some graphics design crowdsourcing sites *might* accept a "volunteer/for free" project category. Contributors would be interested to contribute to such projects to increase their visible portfolios, exposure, reputation and ultimately their chances of participating/winning in paid projects.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a fundraising area that asks your audiences to donate to help pay for the costs. Aside from that, you would generally want to try some volunteering initiatives. You could also consider the nature of the project, and attempt to market it to be more attractive to graphic designers.

Like always, give them credit for their work. It's their work that's making your software look pretty at first glance anyways. :)

Comment: `It's their work that's making your software look pretty at first glance anyways.` It might, but it's a matter of perspective. To the programmers, the source code should be more interesting to look at than the UI. Messy UI can be fixed, messy code is the moment to leave.